# set Jenkins build description for another job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, continuous-integration

Is it possible to set build description for another job? (not the one where script is executed) using Groovy system script?

I know build description can be set like this for current build:

```
Thread.currentThread().executable.setDescription("")
```

But how to do it for another not-related job ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using **jenkins CLI** , use the `set-build-description` command.